# How to install rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to install rails 2.3.8 and 1.8.7 on my ubuntu 13.04 please any one can tell
the commands.

Comment: You can't find it in the internet? `apt-get install ruby1.8 rubygems` `gem install rails -v=2.3.8`

Comment: can you tell me the steps?

Comment: I wrote you 2 commands, just execute them in console. Then try `ruby -v` and `rails -v` to check installed versions.

Comment: I installed ruby 1.8.7 n rails 2.3.8 but when I create new project it is giving error.

Comment: Ok add it as answer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow the steps those have been listed in this [blog](http://programming-ror.blogspot.in/2011_09_01_archive.html), Also choose the specific versions of ruby and rails those  you want to install.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

In console:
`apt-get install ruby1.8 rubygems`
`gem install rails -v=2.3.8`
To check installed versions:
`ruby -v`
`rails -v`